# How to overcome maximum recursion depth exceeded error here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

The problem statement is as follows:

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.

> sum67([1, 2, 2]) → 5 
> sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]) → 5 
> sum67([1, 1, 6, 7, 2]) → 4

I'm aware of the same problem being posted here on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484048/codingbat-python-list-2-sum67/57484301) but I don't want to request a new solution, rather I want to know what might be the problems with my own recursive solution to the problem.

My attempt:

```
def sum67(nums):
  def rem67(nums):
    if 6 not in nums:
      return nums
    index6 = nums.index(6)
    index7 = nums.index(7)
    nums = nums[:index6] + nums[(index7 + 1):]
    return rem67(nums)
  return sum(rem67(nums))
```

The server keeps throwing [maximum recursion depth exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it) error which I'm unable to rectify on the server. Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Your `rem67` will break if the first `7` comes before the first `6`.

Comment: @0x5453 Thank you. I've changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @0x5453 's comment, I modified the index7 which now looks for only those 7 which come after we encounter 6.

Here's the modified code which works correctly:

```
def sum67(nums):
  def rem67(nums):
    if 6 not in nums:
      return nums
    index6 = nums.index(6)
    index7 = nums[index6:].index(7) + index6
    nums = nums[:index6] + nums[(index7 + 1):]
    return rem67(nums)
  return sum(rem67(nums))
```

Answer (score 2):

The recursion limit is 1000 by default. You could use a `while true` instead, like:

```
def sum67(nums):
    while True:
        if 6 not in nums:
            break
        index6 = nums.index(6)
        index7 = nums.index(7)
        nums = nums[:index6] + nums[(index7 + 1):]
    return sum(nums)
```

Like 0x5453 commented, it breaks if you have a 7 before a 6. So you probably want to add something like this:

```
if index6 > index7:
    return -1
```

Comment: while True doesn't work as it is like you've shown but I figured out a way around it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If a 7 occurs in the array before its 6 counterpart, then on one iteration the new array formed in `rem67()` will be composed of a section with a 7 but no 6, followed by a section with a 6. This sets up the same condition in the new array, which will result in infinite recursion.

If it is allowed that two consecutive 7's may occur, or for a 7 to occur first, then it would be better to do the following:

`index7 = nums.index(7, index6)`

This makes index7 reference the first 7 that follows the 6, thus ignoring any 7's that may occur before the 6.

Otherwise returning an error code as suggested by Sefan is good.

Hope this fixes things :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a safe mode:

```
import sys

my_limit = sys.getrecursionlimit()
sys.setrecursionlimit(my_limit + 200)
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```