# How to find a specific item in a list/string/range following an item specified?

Tags: python

Given an **input** sequence of any type (list/string/range) how do I find the next item in the **input** following the specified item?

Also, if the item isn't present or nothing follows it, the function should return `None`.

I tried converting input type to a list and then finding the position from a list, then getting the next item but this does not work for all input types. I have written something but I know it is not pythonic and it also times out. (codewars challenge: https://www.codewars.com/kata/542ebbdb494db239f8000046/train/python)

***My attempt:***

```
def next_item(xs, item):
    xs_list = list(xs)
    if item in xs_list:
        position = xs_list.index(item)
        try:
            return xs_list[position+1]
        except IndexError:
            return None
    else:
        return None
```

***Desired results:***

```
next_item([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 5)
# 6)
next_item(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd')
# None)
next_item(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c')
# None)
next_item('testing', 't')
# # 'e')
next_item(iter(range(1, 3000)), 12)
# , 13)
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo I had added the `codewars` tag, what's wrong with it?

Comment: It doesn't add any important information about the question. Stack Overflow is not a reference source for coding sites. It is a Q & A site for programming problems. Where those problems came from doesn't really matter...

Comment: @Tomerikoo But it helps people interested in codewars find codewars things, just like any other tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to return the element that comes after the specified one:

```
def next_item(seq, e):
    iterable = iter(seq)
    for i in iterable:
        if i == e:
            return next(iterable, None)
    return None


print(next_item([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 5))
print(next_item(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd'))
print(next_item(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c'))
print(next_item('testing', 't'))
print(next_item(iter(range(1, 3000)), 12))
```

**Output**

```
6
None
None
e
13
```

Comment: No need for the ```return None``` part

Comment: I'm aware, but *Explicit is better than implicit.*

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel :-P

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution:

```
def next_item(xs, item):
    it = iter(xs)
    item in it
    return next(it, None)
```

The `item in it` tries to find the item and thereby consumes that iterator until it finds the item or until it reaches the end.

Comment: Nice solution, upvoted :) But maybe some explanation would be useful to the user?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I love doing membership tests on iterators :-). Even just did a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69092874/16759116) about that. Added some explanation now.

Comment: I'd _really_ suggest doing `if item in it: return next(it, None)`, though, otherwise that `item in it` line is bound to be "optimized" away by the next dev. Also much more self-explanatory then.

Comment: @tobias_k Hmm, I disagree. That next dev should get fired instead :-). I mean, among other things it means they didn't re-test after their deletion. I also don't think it's much more self-explanatory, in both cases you need to understand that the `in` consumes the iterator until that point. If you do, you understand both, and if you don't, you understand neither. Finally, someone like Dani will come along and request an explicit `return None` in addition. Ugh, no thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def next_item(seq, item):
    seq = iter(seq)
    return next(next((seq for it in seq if item == it), seq), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest Solution after testing,

> ```
> def next_item(ls,item):
>     try:
>         return ls[ls.index(item)+1]
>     except:
>         None
> ```

It took 0.886 to run this.

Here's are some other solutions,

1. Using a for loop.

> ```
> def next_item(ls,item):
>     for i in range(len(ls)):
>         if ls[i] == item:
>             return ls[i+1]
>     return None
> ```

```
next_item(range(100000000),9999999)
```

**OUTPUT** 1.862

```
[10000000]
```

2. Using `list.index()`

> ```
> def next_item(ls,item):
>     try:
>         return ls[ls.index(item)+1]
>     except:
>         None
> ```

```
next_item(range(100000000),9999999)
```

**OUTPUT** 0.886

```
[10000000]
```

3. Shortest but,
   None is outputed as `[]` and Any answer is inside a list, ex: `[1]`

> ```
> def next_item(ls,item):
>     return [ls[i+1] for i in range(len(ls)) if ls[i] == item]
> ```

```
next_item(range(100000000),9999999)
```

**OUTPUT** 16.481

```
[10000000]
```

4. (3) with the problem solved

> ```
> def next_item(ls,item):
>     a = [ls[i+1] for i in range(len(ls)) if ls[i] == item]
>     if a == []:
>         return None
>     else:
>         return a[0]
> ```

```
next_item(range(100000000),9999999)
```

**OUTPUT** 16.389

```
[10000000]
```

5. What everyone else suggested,

> ```
> def next_item(ls, item):
>     ls = iter(ls)
>     return next(next((ls for i in ls if item == i), ls), None)
> ```

```
next_item(range(100000000),9999999)
```

**OUTPUT** 0.994

```
[10000000]
```

Comment: Both fail a test there.

Comment: Hmm, "fixed" in the sense that the "What everyone else suggested" solution probably works. The other four all fail there.